# Using Multiple SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I have an android app with its own SharedPreferences file called "settings.xml". It is stored under res folder:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(my_package.R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

I use a library that has its own SharedPreferences file called library_settings.xml:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(library_package.R.xml.library_settings);
    }
}
```

However, when I deploy my app. Only one of them is copied. I am able to use my own settings.xml using:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GlobalApplication.getAppContext());
return prefs.getBoolean("some_key", true);
```

How do I programmatically access library_settings.xml SharedPreferences values? Also, library_settings.xml is not getting copied to the app folder i.e., /data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026088/android-using-sharedpreferences-in-a-library  is similar