# how to call getResouces() in a class that is not extended Activity?

Tags: java, android

I would like to call getResouces in some classes, however, these classes are not extended to Activity. How to do it in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a pointer to your activity from which you should call getApplicationContext(). In certain cases you would want to use the regular getContext().

Answer (score 2):

You must either construct said class with a Context object (Activity extends Context), or pass it into the classes's methods where it's needed. Get used to passing Context around everywhere, that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

If passing the Context by parameter is too complicated maybe you are interested in getting the Context statically by using the `Application` class as described here:
[Accessing SharedPreferences through static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods/3806138#3806138)

Answer (score -1):

Or make a public static Activity variable. On the oncreate set it with the context of the activity running behind and use it.