# Android SharedPreferences in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am trying to read SharedPreferences inside Fragment. My code is what I use to get preferences in any other Activity.

```
     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
```

I get error

```
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSharedPreferences(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper
```

I have tried to follow these links but with no luck [Accessing SharedPreferences through static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods) and 
[Static SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241340/static-sharedpreferences). Thank you for any solution.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

The method `getSharedPreferences` is  a method of the `Context` object, so just calling getSharedPreferences from a `Fragment` will not work...because it is not a Context! (Activity is an extension of Context, so we can call getSharedPreferences from it).

So you have to get your applications Context by

```
// this = your fragment
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: getSharedPreferences("pref",0); zero(0) means what private/public?

Comment: @Kailas correct, the mode, ie WORLD_READABLE ect.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: what type of mode i used the shared preferences only access by that application none other application read/write that shared preferences values?

Comment: 0 is analogous to MODE_PRIVATE (or Context.MODE_PRIVATE if used within a class that isn't an extension of Context, such as a Fragment). It means only the app in question can access the preferences. You shouldn't use WORLD_READABLE or WORLD_WRITEABLE as they are deprecated in API 17+, not to mention a security threat.

Comment: is this `this` keyword necessary when doing `this.getActivity().getShared..`?

Comment: @Subby no, explicitly calling just "this" is never necessary. I did it out of personal preference as i hate ambiguous method calls. The only time "this" is required is when you are trying to access a parent non static object when you are out of its scope being in an anonymous inner class/interface.

Comment: Only the simple trick is "Don't declare the SharedPreferences below the curly bracket of the fragment class ". I just used it inside the " onViewCreated " method and worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

The marked answer didn't work for me, I had to use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

EDIT:

Or just try removing the `this`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: The marked answer didn't work for you because you are accessing default shared preferences. A better design is to store your preferences not as a shared object but in a separate and private space, which is what the question and answer is about here.

Answer (score 8):

As a note of caution this answer provided by the user above me is correct.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
```

However, if you attempt to get anything in the fragment before onAttach is called getActivity() will return null.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the `SharedPrefences` in `onAttach` method of fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
```

Check here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs

Answer (score 2):

Given a fragment, you can setup your SharedPreferences like so:

```
val sharedPreferences = activity!!.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(TAG,   Context.MODE_PRIVATE) // kotlin
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(TAG,   Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // java
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` and `onAttach()` didnot help me in same situation
maybe I did something wrong
but! I found another decision
I have created a field `Context thisContext` inside my Fragment
And got a current context from method onCreateView
and now I can work with shared pref from fragment

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
...   
thisContext = container.getContext();   
...   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To define the preference in Fragment:**

`SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CargaDatosCR",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor.putString("credi_credito",cre);
editor.commit();`

**To call another activity or fragment the preference data:**
`SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CargaDatosCR", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
credit=pref.getString("credi_credito","");
if(credit.isNotEmpty)...`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is helpfull to someone after few years.
New way, on Androidx, of getting `SharedPreferences()` inside fragment is to implement into `gradle dependencies`

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
```

and then, inside fragment call

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
preferences = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a context from within a `Fragment`

Just do

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yout_fragment_layout, container, false);
        // get context here
        Context context = getContext();
        // do as you please with the context


        // if you decide to go with second option
        SomeViewModel someViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel.class);
        Context context = homeViewModel.getContext();
        // do as you please with the context
        return root;
    }
}
```

You may also attached an `AndroidViewModel` in the `onCreateView` method that implements a method that returns the application context

```
public class SomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> someMutableData;
    Context context;

    public SomeViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();
        someMutableData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        .
        .
     }

     public Context getContext() {
         return context
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use requiredactivity in fragment kotlin

```
 val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(loginmasuk.LOGIN_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Current Date and Time or get each every attributes from it:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yy   HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        String timeStamp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String timeStamp2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.print(timeStamp1);
        if(timeStamp1.contains("10/03/21")) {
            System.out.print("\ntrue");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("false");
        }
```