# How to save Arraylist of Objects from Fragment class into SharedPreferencess

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I saw similar questions in stackoverflow ( [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) , [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741270/android-sharedpreferences-in-fragment) ) and other [websites](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Save-ArrayList-of-Object-into-Shared-Preferences-in-Android/510?page=10&ppage=3) . They are doing everything from an Activity hence they didn't get problem.

I have an Activity and Fragment class. I am trying to save **ArrayList of Object** into **shared preferences** from a **Fragment**. Below is what i tried

```
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            try {
               editor.putString("taggedFriends",ObjectSerializer.serialize(taggableFriends));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Its showing error at **ObjectSerializer**

```
**Cannot resolve symbom 'ObjectSerializer'**
```

I tried

```
getActivity.ObjectSerializer.serialize(..);
```

But error didn't go. Help me what can i do now.

**Thankyou** for spending time for me.

Comment: Convert it to json string and save. Than when you need to access read from pref and convert json string to object and use. You can use gson for converting json

Comment: Can you show demo in Answer @savepopullation

Comment: i post an example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Last edit:

In this case:

```
 static class YourObject
{
    private String _name;

    public YourObject(String name)
    {
        this._name = name;  
    } 
}


YourObject yourObject = new YourObject(myName);
ArrayList<YourObject> foo = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
foo.add(yourObject);
```

convert an ArrayList to JSONArray:

```
  JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(foo);
```

Then save the JSONArray:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putString("yourStringName", mJSONArray.toString());
```

String to JSONArray:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_FILE",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myJSONArrayString = prefs.getString("yourStringName", "");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJSONArrayString);
```

JSONArray to ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
   for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   }
```

I hope this solve your question.

Comment: You are using ArrayList<String> but i am using ArrayList<Object> , will it cause any problem >

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and then say you. :) Please wait for a minute

Comment: It would be useful if you say me how to retrive it in another activity. .

Comment: : Sorry , it may be my problem in my Class. I don't know how to solve it. I'll write another question and paste link here. Will you please wait for 10 minutes. I really need your help . Thanks..

Comment: I think your code is correct, but i am having some other issues in my Class. I hope you can solve it . I'll paste my another questions link here in 5 minutes. Please help me....

Comment: Ok no problem ill wait

Comment: Sorry to make you wait... here is the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132418/why-cant-i-use-my-arraylist-variable-outside-facebookcallback" .

Comment: The Apoorva answer solve your question, put the code inside onSuccess .

Comment: I just did, now its having a value. I followed your method but i got a problem .  -->  JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(foo); <-- After this, i checked with Log.d(TAG,mJSONArray.toString()); , what i got is null

Comment: Are you sure if taggableFriends is not null?

Comment: Yes i am sure. @Fabio Venturi Pastor

Comment: You can see on this example how to convert Arraylist in a JsonArray:
https://javanotes2all.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/convert-arraylist-to-jsonarray/
Im not sure what is your problem but now im at work, in 2 hrs ill help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97401/discussion-between-fabio-venturi-pastor-and-ganesh).

Answer (score 1):

First add Gson to your gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Convert your list to Json String like below:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
foo.add("Item1");
foo.add("Item2");
foo.add("Item3");

String json = new Gson().toJson(foo );
```

And save it to shared pref like below:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
mEditor.putString("yourKey", json);
```

And when you want to use read your saved json string from pref:

```
String json = mPrefs.getString("yourKey", "");
```

Convert your Json String to list of your objects like below. In example i used String.

```
ArrayList<String> foo = (ArrayList<String>) new Gson().fromJson(json,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    }.getType());
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. will it work for ArrayList<Object> . What you are saying is for <String> ...  Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It'll work for your custom objects too. If you have problem we can discuss.

Comment: Also another doubt. I am having object of ArrayList<Object> . Can i use ArrayList<obj> obj  .toJson(obj) or Do i need to use only List<obj> object ?

Comment: Its saying casting these is redundent while retreving, shall i remove casting in this line 'ArrayList<String> foo = (ArrayList<String>) new Gson().fromJson(json,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    }.getType());'

Comment: its just storing "[ ]" value in json string. :-/ its not actually storing any string.