# getSharedPreferences Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to save data on Activity and read on the Fragment.

```
public void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(kekoyaz,mykey );
        editor.apply();


        Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Load data on fragment

```
public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String beimtext = sharedPreferences.getString(kekoyaz, "");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "bu"+beimtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But getSharedPreferences turn red on the fragment and it's suggested to create SharedPreferences method. So I did and there is no error left.

```
private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String sharedPrefs, int modePrivate) {
        return null;
    }
```

I get error when I run the app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.prestige.user, PID: 32516
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.prestige.user.BlankFragment.loadData(BlankFragment.java:1918)
                      at com.prestige.user.BlankFragment.onCreateView(BlankFragment.java:1898)
```

**UPDATE**

I removed this line

```
/*private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String sharedPrefs, int modePrivate) {
        return null;
    }*/
```

and I use your code

```
public void loadData() {
        getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);    
        String beimtext = sharedPreferences.getString(kekoyaz);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "bu"+beimtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I add

```
private ResourceBundle sharedPreferences;
```

But I got an error again.

Comment: **getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);** try this

Comment: Well, what do you expect when you have a method that returns null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SharedPreferences in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741270/android-sharedpreferences-in-fragment)

Comment: Actually when I add "SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);" I got no error but my value doesn't show up.Only text appear string text "bu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After you update your question, you `getSharedPreferences()` with `Activity` but did't assign `sharedPreferences` variable value**

[image]

---

**Replace your code with below**.

```
public void loadData() {
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);    
        String beimtext = sharedPreferences.getString(kekoyaz);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "bu"+beimtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Answer is correct.Thank you.Just mini edit. String beimtext = sharedPreferences.getString(kekoyaz,"");

Answer (score 0):

This is because [getSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) need a Context.

So, you can use the following:

```
getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
```