# Calling SharedPreferences from DialogFragment inside onClick of another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm querying `SharedPreferences` inside a `DialogFragment` class called from the `onClick` method of another fragment.

I've followed these links, but with no luck: [Android SharedPreferences in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741270/android-sharedpreferences-in-fragment), [Accessing SharedPreferences through static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods), [Static SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241340/static-sharedpreferences).

My code is as follows:

QueryPreferences.java:

```
public class QueryPreferences
{
    private static final String PREF_FIRST_RUN = "firstRun";

    public static Boolean getFirstRun(Context context)
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(PREF_FIRST_RUN, true);
    }

    public static void setFirstRun(Context context, boolean firstRun)
    {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean(PREF_FIRST_RUN, firstRun)
                .apply();
    }
}
```

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String DIALOG_CHOOSER = "DialogChooser";

    private TextView mTextView;

    public static MainFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.some_text);

        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                SomeDialogFragment dialog = new SomeDialogFragment();
                dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_CHOOSER);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

SomeDialogFragment:

```
public class SomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{    
    private boolean firstRun = QueryPreferences.getFirstRun(context);
}
```

I do not know what to put in "`context`" in the `SomeDialogFragment` code snippet above.

Whatever i have tried give me a `NullPointerException`.

The things i have tried so far are:

- `SomeDialogFragment.this.getParentFragment().getActivity()`
- `SomeDialogFragment.this`
- `SomeDialogFragment.this.getActivity()`
- `SomeDialogFragment.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()`
- `SomeDialogFragment.this.getParentFragment().getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

EDIT: I'm calling `firstRun` from an inner class.

Comment: You need to wait onCreate() to assign your field. `SomeDialogFragment.this.getActivity()` should work for context

Answer (score 0):

context can be acquired when the fragment is first created in onCreate Method

```
class SomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{    
   private boolean firstRun;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      firstRun = QueryPreferences.getFirstRun(getContext());
   }       
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public class SomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private boolean firstRun;  
    private Context context;  
    public SomeDialogFragment()
    {  
        context = getActivity();  
        firstRun = QueryPreferences.getFirstRun(context);  
    }   
}
```