# getsharedpreferences from custom edittext context

Tags: android, preferences, android-context

I have a custom edittext class I have made that I'd like to retrieve some sharedpref values from a prefs xml. I am currently getting the context passed on the constructor and running getsharedpreferences off that. This crashes the app, though. How would I go about reading the values from there?

Code snippet:

```
public class RichEditText extends EditText {
        Context acontext;
        SharedPreferences synpref;
    public RichEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        acontext=context;
        synpref = acontext.getSharedPreferences("synexp", 0);
        Log.v("MyApp",synpref.getString("exp", "value"));
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> 08-20 20:57:06.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eyecreate/com.eyecreate.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.eyecreate.RichEditText 
>   08-20 20:57:06.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13343): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 08-20 20:57:06.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13343): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException The Null pointer exception was on the line with getSharedPreferences

Comment: Can you post the logcat log of the exception?

Comment: maybe `context` is null?

Comment: yes, it seems context is null.

Comment: so pass a real context, not null...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods/3806138#3806138). This way you can get preferences from any part of code.