# Accessing SharedPreferences without context

Tags: android

I have read question : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods) about reading shared preferences. But they still need Context to access SharedPreferences. I want to know how to access SharedPreferences without context. Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply _can't_, but as long as your application is running there is an _Application Context_ available to be used...

Comment: You can't. It needs a context.

Comment: If you can elaborate on why you need it that way, maybe we can help you more with that.

Comment: I built my own library very long time ago, full of static methods. But now, I want to modify that library to save some user preferences. I can pass context every static method call, but that will force me to refactor entire classes in my application.

Comment: @K-ballo: How to get <i>ApplicationContext</i>?

Comment: I do not think you will have to refactor. Inside your class, use the getApplicationContext() method and store it as a static class variable. Then use this Context variable in the static methods where you are using SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solve my problem by retrieve ApplicationContext first ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)) and then use that context to get SharedPreferences. thank K-ballo.

Answer (score 8):

Application Class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

}
```

Declare the Application in the AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
/>
```

Usage:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());
```

Comment: context is a big data, its not good that be a static object(memory leak and...)

Comment: It is impossible to generate a SharePrefs if there is no Context

Answer (score 6):

We can have SharedPreference instance to use in a helper class having Getters and Setters, Without involving context explained [**here**](http://www.freakyjolly.com/shared-preference-context-error-android/)

In **MainActivity** add

```
public static SharedPreferences preferences;
preferences = getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then in **PreferenceHelper** use set and get as

```
public static void setName(String value) {
    MainActivity.preferences.edit().putString(KEY_DEMO_NAME, value ).commit();
}
public static String getName() {
    return MainActivity.preferences.getString(KEY_DEMO_NAME,"");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oded's answer got me what I needed for my callback method in my utility class. In my case I needed a kotlin version which looks like this.

manifest

```
android:name=".SGAutoApp"
```

SGAutoApp.kt

```
class SGAutoApp : Application() {
    companion object {
        fun getAppContext(): Context {
            return this.getAppContext()
        }
    }
}
```

and then it's like below in my utility class callback method.

```
            val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SGAutoApp.getAppContext())
```

Comment: This is going to loop? you're calling `getAppContext` inside `getAppContext`