# How to get SharedPreferences from non-Context class and without using non-final static variables?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, static-methods, static-members

I need to get a reference to the shared prefs from inside an abstract class called `A` that does not extend anything.

I cannot pass a `Context` object to this class to get the shared prefs because being abstract, I don't instantiate it. I created class `A` to be extended by other POJOs that share a single attribute, which is the `uuid`. The UUID is generated once in the app on its first run, which is why I store it in the shared prefs. In class `A`'s constructor, I'm hoping to set the `uuid` based on what is in the shared prefs.

```
public abstract class A {
    private String uuid;
    public A() {
        // this is how I'm hoping to use the shared preferences
        this.uuid = sharedPrefs.getString("KEY_UUID", "null");
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

[One suggestion I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806138/855680) is to extend `Application`, say in a class called `App`, and include an attribute `android:name=".App"` in the `<application>` tag in the manifest. I imagine `App` will be written like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static App app;
    public void onCreate() {
        this.app = this;
    }
    public static App getApp() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

...so that from inside class `A`, I can do this:

```
this.uuid = App.getApp().getSharedPreferences("prefs_name.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("KEY_UUID", "null");
```

However, doesn't the non-final static field `app` lose its reference to the `App` and become null when Android kills off the process or when the phone restarts? How can I get a reference to the shared prefs without using this method? Or should I just manually write the UUID to a file?

Comment: try this http://www.freakyjolly.com/shared-preference-context-error-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot pass a Context object to this class to get the shared prefs because being abstract, I don't instantiate it.

Sure you can. Put `Context` as a parameter on the constructor. Or, put `SharedPreferences` as a parameter on the constructor, if you prefer. Your subclasses' constructors will need to take the same parameter and pass it to the `super()` call.

> However, doesn't the non-final static field app lose its reference to the App and become null when Android kills off the process or when the phone restarts?

Well, the whole process is gone. Saying that it loses "its reference to the App and become null" is akin to saying that a person at ground zero of a nuclear blast will get a sunburn just prior to being vaporized -- while probably true, the point is a bit moot. :-)

Comment: I was worried that passing `this` from activities and services that instantiate the child POJOs and then passing it on to `A` is not good design. But I guess I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: @MattQuiros: Then don't pass `this`. Pass `SharedPreferences`. Or, better yet, pass the actual UUID string. Or, even better yet, if this UUID is unique for the whole process ("The UUID is generated once in the app on its first run, which is why I store it in the shared prefs"), put that in a static data member and skip loading it in each POJO.

Comment: The UUID is actually a unique identifier of the app installation, so it should never be generated again unless the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. So I suppose I can't do your last suggestion and simply pass the UUID instead of `this` or the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @MattQuiros: "So I suppose I can't do your last suggestion" -- my last suggestion was to cache the UUID in a static data member. You can certainly do that. Just initialize that static data member from your `SharedPreferences` before you start creating POJOs. You must already be doing a before-any-POJOs check to *create* that UUID on first run, so just stash the new-or-existing UUID in a static data member at that point. BTW, bear in mind that your UUID will be different for different users of the same device on Android 4.2+.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on 4.2, however if I store the UUID in a static data member, it will return to its original state when the process is killed off or the phone restarted. I tested it just now, initialized a global static `int` to `-1` and incremented its values in the activity. When I restarted the phone and launched the app again, the `int`'s value is back to `-1`. I hope I understood you correctly?

Comment: @MattQuiros: Use the static data member as a **cache**. The backing store is your `SharedPreferences`, which are persistent.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your App class to something like this:

```
public class App extends Application
{
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        App.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getStaticContext()
    {
        return App.context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same effect as the `App` code in the question?